# Best practice for Data Integration using a .csv flat file into Salesforce (<100 rows of data)

Tags: integration, data-loader

I am trying to find a best practice of data integration using a .csv flat file into Salesforce database.

I am trying to schedule this task once a day.

Sorry. this is not a code-related question, but I am trying to get a better idea what methods are out there at this moment.

I am trying to import and append data (not whole a lot). I am looking at about <100 rows of data a day (two columns).

So, I am not sure **Data Loader** is necessary (since I heard that this is for Bulk of data).

I have Unlimited Edition of Salesforce.

Should I just use a Python file and execute to run on the server to import   data into Salesforce database?

Or is there other **API** that could be used with Salesforce?

Comment: I have used email services to parse daily csv before and the external system emails the file daily (no one willing to write code / install DL on external system) . But if you can use rest or soap API it would be better if you can get the code written on the external end

Answer (score 2):

The Data Loader is typically used for bulk records, but it doesn't have to be. The Data Loader is a ready-made solution that you can just drop on to a server somewhere, write a crontab, Windows Task, etc, to run daily and perform your insert/update operations. Of course, there's also a SOAP and REST API, if you decide to write your own code, but I'd investigate using the Data Loader first, since it doesn't involve writing any code. See the [Data Loader CLI](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=using_the_command_line_interface.htm&type=0) docs for more info.

Comment: Thanks! I will investigate the Data Loader option first.

Comment: If I have a Linux server that will be used to schedule daily task, what is best practice?

Comment: @KingJava Write a script to call the Data Loader, set up crontab to run daily. There's really no special magic. It's pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any URL I could read about regards to "writing a script"?

Comment: @KingJava [crontab](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm) explains the basic syntax, and [Data Loader Command-Line Syntax](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=using_the_command_line_interface.htm&type=0) for specific parameters you need.

Comment: But it says "The Data Loader command-line interface is supported for Windows only." Should I use Wine inside Linux machine?

Comment: @KingJava Oh, thanks for pointing that out. You actually do need to use the [open-source](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader) version instead; full instructions are included.

Comment: Looks like you gave me a Christmas gift. This site looks legit. So, this is the solution for Linux for data loading using csv file?

Comment: I am having difficulty with following the steps on the Open Source version (https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader) since I am not familiar with command line. Is there any path/forum I could get help?

Comment: @kingjava I can help you setup for free. Where do I reach you?

Comment: @singularity Thanks for your offer. I was able to download the app finally yesterday.  There were so many issues to download and execute this application. And syntax errors on instructions, too. Now I am facing login issue when I tried to use.  I created this issue on Github's log. https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/issues/141  You could reach me at  kudohsbiz@gmail.com